# Apply css to element "path"

Tags: html, css

Assuming that there are many elements in a webpage how do i apply CSS to:

- All the `<hr>` that are AFTER an unordered list
- All the `<hr>` that are AFTER `<div>`
- All the `<span>` which are inside `<p><article>`
- All the `<span>` which are inside `<article>`

Example:

```
#first > p > em
{
    background: #739D00;
    color: #C7F83E;
    padding: .1em;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The appropriate selectors, in order:

```
ul + hr {}
div + hr {}
p > article span {}
article span {}
```

## Remarks:

The `+` selector selects all elements **immediately** after a given element. In general, `A + B`, will cause the first element `B` that follows after any element `A`, to be styled.

You can also use `~` in place of `+`, which would select all elements after a given element, no matter how far after.

**With `ul ~ hr`**

```
<ul></ul>
<hr /><!-- i get styled -->
<hr /><!-- me too -->
<hr /><!-- me too -->
```

**With `ul + hr`**

```
<ul></ul>
<hr /><!-- i get styled -->
<hr /><!-- nope -->
<hr /><!-- nope -->
```

`>` is for direct descendant.

My assumption of your questions:

```
<ul></ul>
<hr /><!-- You want to style THIS -->

<div></div>
<hr /><!-- You want to style THIS -->
<hr /><!-- ... but not this -->

<p>
    <article>
        <!-- there may be more nested elements here... --->
            <span></span><!-- You want to style THIS -->
    </article>
</p>


<article>
    <!-- there may be more nested elements... -->
        <span></span><!-- you want to style THIS -->
</article>
```

Comment: As a note: With the last rule the second to last is not necessarily needed and an article within a p-element is actually not valid HTML.

Comment: @geoff ok got that + is the element after the first, but how do you select ALL the <hr> that are after <div> ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use those selectors:

- [Next-sibling combinator](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) (`+`)

  For example, `ul + hr` matches all `hr` that are immediately preceded by an `ul` (ignoring non-element nodes).
- [Following-sibling combinator](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#general-sibling-combinators) (`~`)

  For example, `ul ~ hr` matches all `hr` that are preceded (not necessarily immediately) by an `ul`.
- [Child combinator](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#child-combinators) (`>`)

  For example, `article > span` matches all `span` that are children of an `article`.
- [Descendant combinator](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#descendant-combinators) ()

  For example, `article span` matches all `span` that are  descendants of an `article`.

Comment: taking note of this but ill give the right answer to the guy  below :P

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<hr>`, use border-bottom

article is a block-level item that essentially replaces a `<div>` tag, and `<p>` tags should be within `<article>`,

```
article {border-bottom:#C3F 8px solid}
article span {font-size:200%; color:#C3F}

ul {border-bottom:#C3F 8px solid}
```

and in html, looks like this:

```
<article>
 <h1>article headline</h1>
 <p> My paragraph here <span> with a span section</span> and a border below the article, not paragraph.</p>
 <p>Another paragraph here</p>
 </article>
 <ul><li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item two</l>
  </ul>
```